# How many inodes does a folder use?

Tags: inode

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

I have a folder with lots (several hundreds thousands) files.

I would like to see how many [inodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) does this folder use on the file system.

How to achieve that?

The [`df -i`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/df) command applies on the whole file system, I need to be "folder-specific".

Comment: `du` will do inodes, too. See `man du`.

Comment: I am actually not able to find the word 'inode' on the [du manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/du). Is that normal? Does it use a synonym? If so, which one is it?

Comment: look again, it's --inodes

Comment: you seemed right, this manpage is more up-to-date: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/du.1.html